# How to test contenteditable field with Protractor?

Tags: javascript, protractor, contenteditable

I have WYSIWYG editor on my page.
I would like to test saving text in this editor with protractor.

It looks like standard **sendKeys** does not work.

Currently I'm getting an error:

```
UnknownError: unknown error: cannot focus element
```

What should I do in this case?

Error output:

`UnknownError: unknown error: cannot focus element
  (Session info: chrome=41.0.2272.118)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Mac OS X 10.10.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 58 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver`

Comment: Can you get a screenshot of the page (or the full DOM state) when it throws that error? That might aid in debugging.

Comment: thanks a lot, you pushed me to understand the problem!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake.
I have been selecting not the editor **itself**, but **content inside** editor.
Now it works.